What's the difference between Math.max() and Int.coerceAtLeast() in Kotlin?

val num1 = 5
val num2 = 10

val maxNum = Math.max(num1, num2)
val maxNum = num1.coerceAtLeast(num2)

Int.coerceAtLeast() is recommended in Kotlin, but I think Math.max() is more readable. Are there any other advantages of Int.coerceAtLeast()?

As you said, this is mainly about readability. Functionally they do the same thing, but semantically, they express different intentions.
max(a, b) strongly suggests that a and b are equally "important", and you want to pick whichever is larger. For example, suppose you are printing two lines of text, and you want to put them in a box. You would use max to calculate how wide that box should be.
fun printTwoLinesInABox(line1: String, line2: String) {
    val boxWidth = max(line1.length, line2.length)
    println("-".repeat(boxWidth + 2))
    println("|${line1.padEnd(boxWidth)}|")
    println("|${line2.padEnd(boxWidth)}|")
    println("-".repeat(boxWidth + 2))
}

a.coerceAtLeast(b) strongly suggests that you are want to use a, but that you want the result to be at least b. Unlike max, there is an imbalance in the roles of a and b here.
For example, if you want to print one line of text in a box, and you want the box to not be too small - at least 20 characters wide for example.
fun printLineInBox(line: String) {
    val boxWidth = line.length.coerceAtLeast(20)
    println("-".repeat(boxWidth + 2))
    println("|${line.padEnd(boxWidth)}|")
    println("-".repeat(boxWidth + 2))
}

"At least" is the key phrase here. If it is natural to use "at least" to describe what your code is doing, you should use coerceAtLeast. In the printTwoLinesInABox example, it is difficult to form a sentence describing the box's width using the phrase "at least", so it makes more sense to use max.

Side note: Math.max is only available on Kotlin/JVM. The common function is a global function called max.

As a general rule, Kotlin authors try to not duplicate the functionality. Contrary to e.g. Java, whenever they decide they need to change or rename something in the stdlib, they usually make the old function immediately obsolete. This happened with e.g. String.capitalize() or Iterable.sumBy().
So why is it different here? I think the main difference is that conceptually the Math.max is for numbers and coerceAtLeast is for any comparable objects.
If we need to get a max value of multiple numbers, we usually look the stdlib for the "max" function. We would never think of something like "coerceAtLeast". Also, "math" itself is obviously about numbers and this is the place where such functionality should be naturally located. So Math.max is what we look for and if it isn't there, it might cause frustration.
Now, we also have the Comparable interface, so potentially we could get a "max" of such objects as well. However, this case is much different and more complicated. First of all, it is not about numbers, so "math" doesn't really fit here very well. Second, if we do max(5, 5), then it doesn't matter which "5" we return. It is different in the case of Comparable where it is important to know which one is returned in the case of equal objects. This asymmetry makes the "symmetric" function like: max(obj1, obj2) not a very good choice. obj1.coerceAtLeast(obj2) is much more clear on the fact that it favors the obj1 in case of equal objects.
Ok, we separated numbers and comparables, what about the duplication? Well, numbers are comparables, so coerceAtLeast can be used for them as well. And it is always better to have an optimized overload like: Int.coerceAtLeast(Int).
Summing up:

Math.max is not good for Comparable.
coerceAtLeast is not ideal as a general "maximum number" functionality.
Because numbers are naturally comparable, that causes the duplication.

